# outlook autodiscover on nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, exchange

I'm new in nginx reverse proxy
my problem is outlook cant connect to echange server with auto discovery and open IMAP with this config :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name email.mydomain.com;
        return 301 https://email.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen  443;
        server_name email.mydomain.com;
        set $exchange2019 https://internal.ip;

        # Redirect from "/" to "/owa" by default
        rewrite ^/$ https://email.mydomain.com/owa permanent;

        # Enable SSL
        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/email-mobile/Exg-Mobile.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/email-mobile/Exg-Mobile.rsa;
        ssl_session_timeout     5m;

        # Set global proxy settings
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_read_timeout      360;

        proxy_pass_header       Date;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;

        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

#        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
#        proxy_pass_header Authorization;

        location ~* ^/owa      { proxy_pass $exchange2019; }
        location ~* ^/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync { proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; proxy_pass $exchange2016; }
        location ~* ^/ecp { proxy_pass $exchange2019; }
        location ~* ^/Rpc { proxy_pass $exchange2019; }
        #location ~* ^/mailarchiver { proxy_pass https://mailarchiver.local;}
#        location ~* ^/Autodiscover { proxy_pass $exchange2016/Autodiscover; }
#        location ~* ^/autodiscover { proxy_pass $exchange2016/autodiscover; }

        error_log /var/log/nginx/owa-ssl-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/owa-ssl-access.log;
}
server {

        listen  443;
        server_name autodiscover.mydomain.com;
        set $exchange2019 https://internal.ip;
        # Enable SSL
        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/email-mobile/Exg-Mobile.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/email-mobile/Exg-Mobile.rsa;
        ssl_session_timeout     5m;

        # Set global proxy settings
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_read_timeout      360;

        proxy_pass_header       Date;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;

        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;

        location ~* ^/Autodiscover { proxy_pass $exchange2019/Autodiscover; }
        location ~* ^/autodiscover { proxy_pass $exchange2019/autodiscover; }

        error_log /var/log/nginx/owa-ssl-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/owa-ssl-access.log;
}
```

I want to connect to my exchange server from outlook from my internal network and out side with autodiscover but when i add my email address to my outlook IMAP is coming but i want another page in the picture
[image: Error]

Comment: The image doesn't really say/show what the problem is. Please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1084234/edit) the question to add more details about what is not actually working.

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for the help, I changed the picture

Comment: Adding a `!` before the square bracket to inline the image. Also add text to describe the problem as not everybody can view images.

Comment: i cant do this because of reputation @hardillb

Comment: I've done it, it will need to be approved. But you still need to add text to describe the error